# LC Oscillator Simulation

Tags: oscillator, ltspice

I am designing a LC CMOS Tail injection based Oscillator but somehow the node voltages are constantly showing errors.
The circuit schematics are
[image]

The properties of MOSFETs are as followed:

[image]

Node Voltages:
[image]

I am getting weird results in which the Node Voltages are constantly shooting up to Mega-Volts range.
It would be helpful if you could suggest what am I doing wrong possibly.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Off topic, but unless you turned the text anchors to be visible on purpose (the small circles), if you press `A` you'll toggle them back to be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ideal tank, add a resistor in parallel with the LC tank, should work then.
Also, you have a floating node between the drains of the MOS. Split the inductor as a series combination of two 0.04nH inductors and connect the node in between to VDD/2 = 1.25V. Will definitely work then.

Comment: Tried using the Resistors with values ranging from 100ohms to 1M ohms in parallel to the LC tank, but didn't help.

Comment: @AkshChordia Also try a small resistor in series with the inductor. May or may not help.

Comment: @AkshChordia See edits\

Comment: @sarthak Thanks! Your suggestion works.
By the time I also realised that I was a bit harsh using a constant current source. I tried inserting an N-MOS always in saturation for tail current injection initially but didn't help initially.
Adjusting the Initial conditions and changing the LC values makes the circuit work.